# Clothed brands that might be used for idol worship

Tags: halacha, clothing, avodah-zarah

Is wearing clothes that have a tag in the back or in the front considered idolatry if you don’t know if someone might idolize the brand?

Should you rip off the tag if you don’t know if someone might be idolizing the brand?

Comment: In what way do you think someone would worship the brand?

Comment: is there a larger concern with clothing than with any othe named object?

Comment: The English term idolize, to worship as if it were an idol, doesn't mean in a halachic sense.

Comment: Can you give an example of such tags

Answer (score 4):

The essence of idolatry according to Judaism is ([Rambam MT Avoda Zara 2:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912360/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Two.htm))

> the worship of false gods is **not to serve any of the creations, not an
> angel, a sphere, or a star, none of the four fundamental elements, nor
> any entity created from them**.

The idolatry which is punished is when someone worships a particular idol in the way it is commonly worshiped ([Rambam MT Avoda Zara 3:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912361/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Three.htm))

> **The gentiles established various different services for each
> particular idol and image.** These services do not [necessarily]
> resemble each other. For example, Pe'or is served by defecating before
> it. Marculis is served by throwing stones at it or clearing stones
> away from it. Similarly, other services were instituted for other
> idols.
>
> One who defecates before Marculis or throws a stone at Pe'or is free
> of liability until he serves it according to the accepted modes of
> service [...] For this reason, a court must know the types of worship
> [practiced by gentiles], because **an idolater is stoned to death only
> when we know that [he has worshiped a false god] in the mode in which
> it is traditionally worshiped.**

**As such, wearing clothes with logo or tags do not run the risk of idolatry since I don't believe any idolatry cult worships clothes as gods.**